# Slickgrid - How to update dataView with changed data

Tags: slickgrid

I'm using `grid.onBeforeEditCell` event to make a one-click YesNoCheckboxCellEditor.

Not sure if this is the best way to do this, but here is the code I created for this: 
[Slickgrid - One-click checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927269/slickgrid-one-click-checkboxes/7578002#7578002)

This works fine, but setting the data[] array directly doesn't seem to effect the dataView().

My understanding is that the dataView and data are completely uncoupled, and so when I have a filtered view, my data behind the filtered viewport will be incorrect.

**Based on my code snippet, how do I also update the corresponding cell in the dataView ?**

(I found the dataView.getItembyId  and dataView.updateItem methods but unsure how to use these)

I've also tried: dataView.refresh(), grid.invalidateRow(), grid.render()

BTW, I'm following this example:  http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the grid.onClick instead of onBeforeEditCell.
See the http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example7-events.html example.

Comment: this demo doesn't use dataView

Comment: In case of the DataView, just update the item using `dataView.updateItem()` instead of directly.